# Dynamic auto-completion in JupyterLab

Tags: ipython, jupyter-lab

Can objects implement any magic function that Jupyter uses for field and getitem auto completion on that object? Or can I register a hook with the Jupyter Python kernel to do it? Would be very useful for ORMs, dynamically generated namespaces, dataframes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depends on whether you need attributes (then use the standard `__dir__`) or keys (then implement `_ipython_key_completions_`).